# Query node js, to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

im trying to get data using find with nodejs, express, I'm starting with node js, I have a word for example "hola" then I split it to "[h,o,l,a]" like that and then make a query for each letter and get an url image but then I need to pass to a view, I have this

```
app.post("/palabra", function(req, res) {
    var det = req.body.letra;
    var spl = det.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < spl.length ; i++) {

        Lesho.find({"letra": spl[i]
        }, function(error, documento) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.redirect("loadImg");
            };

        res.render("palabra",{traduccion:documento})  

        });        
    }   
});
```

the thing is that "document" return all the variables but I can't pass it to my view because it's on a for and I can use it outside because it lost value, how can I solve it.

Comment: Don't loop. Use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) i.e `Lesho.find({ "letra": { "$in": spl } },function(error,documento) { ...`. It's just like running all the queries and combining the output.

Comment: I need one by one because if I have the word "did" I need to show 2 image that match with the letter "d" in that order and when I use $in, just show me 1

Comment: Use promises then. Easier to chain the loop that way: `Promise.all(spl.map( letra => Lesho.find({ letra )) )).then( documento => [].concat.apply([],documento) ).then( tradcuccion => res.render("palabra",{ traduccion }) ).catch( err => { console.log(err); res.redirect("loadImg") });` But just don't `for()` or `forEach()` as the inner calls are async and you need to await the results.

Comment: I used it, and it works.

Thanks.